# Elixir punctuation replacement regex

Tags: regex, elixir

I'm trying to remove all punctuation from a string using

```
String.replace(sentence, ~r[\p{P}\p{S}], "")
```

However it's not removing all punctuation! As an illustrative example:

```
iex(1)> String.replace("foo!&^%$?", ~r[\p{P}\p{S}], "")
"foo!?"
```

What should I be using?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Possibly need `/`...`/` as pattern [delimiters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Delimiters):

```
String.replace("foo!&^%$?", ~r/[\p{P}\p{S}]/, "")
```

The result could be explained, because else `[` `]` would be used as delimiters in your sample, which corresponds to `\p{P}\p{S}` as a sequence and results in `foo!?` (see [regex101 example](http://regex101.com/r/iA6vF1/1))

Would additionally add a `+` [quantifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html): `~r/[\p{P}\p{S}]+/`

Comment: This regex will also remove hypens as well such as `co-operative`. @Jonny5 are you able to update your reg ex to not remove hyphens?

Comment: @BenMorganIO You can use a lookbehind: [`[\p{P}\p{S}](?<!-)`](https://regex101.com/r/VYA7R3/1)

Answer (score 2):

If you're only working with strings in English, it's easiest and clearest to just use [POSIX character classes](https://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html):

`String.replace("foo!&^%$?", ~r/[[:punct:]]/, "")`

Answer (score 1):

I'm late to the game, but you have to adjust the regex and customize it, especially if you're trying to preserve certain items, like a hyphen (which is considered punctuation in some language aspects).

My replace is a bit more verbose, but lets me control what I want to replace:

`` String.replace(str, ~r/[!#$%&()*+,.:;<=>?@\^_`{|}~-]/, "") ``

This let me keep the hyphen in a word, like co-operate, while removing `:`or other characters.